# Error while hiding and unhiding the column with hidden subcolumns in extjs

Tags: extjs, grid

I have a grid  with columns as

```
 columns: [
        { header: '<b>Agency </b>', dataIndex: 'Agency ', width: 120, align: 'left', sortable: false, flex: 1,
            summaryType: 'count',
            summaryRenderer: function(value) {
                return Ext.String.format('Total');

            }
         },
        { header: '<b>A</b>',
            columns: [

        { header: '<b>B</b> ', dataIndex: 'B', width: 100, sortable: false, align: 'right', hidden: true,
            summaryType: 'sum',
            summaryRenderer: function(value) {
                return (value.toFixed(2) );

            },
            renderer: function(value) {
            return (value.toFixed(2));
            }
        },
        { header: '<b>C</b>', dataIndex: 'C', width: 100, sortable: false, align: 'right', hidden: true,
           summaryType: 'sum',
           summaryRenderer: function(value) {
             return (value.toFixed(2) );
         },
         renderer: function(value) {
             return (value.toFixed(2));
         }
        },
        { header: '<b>D</b>', dataIndex: 'D', width: 120, sortable: false, align: 'right',
            summaryType: 'sum',
            summaryRenderer: function(value) {
                return (value.toFixed(2) );
            },
            renderer: function(value) {
                return (value.toFixed(2));
            }
        }

        ]
        },
        { header: '<b>E</b>',
            columns: [
                { header: '<b>J</b> ', dataIndex: 'J', width: 110, sortable: false, align: 'right', hidden: true ,
                    summaryType: 'sum',
                    summaryRenderer: function(value) {
                        return (value.toFixed(2));
                    },
                    renderer: function(value) {
                        return (value.toFixed(2));
                    }
                },
                { header: '<b>F</b>', dataIndex: 'F', width: 110, sortable: false, align: 'right', hidden: true,
                    summaryType: 'sum',
                    summaryRenderer: function(value) {
                        return (value.toFixed(2));
                    },
                    renderer: function(value) {
                        return (value.toFixed(2));
                    }
                },
                { header: '<b>J </b>', dataIndex: 'J', width: 130, sortable: false, align: 'right',
                    summaryType: 'sum',
                    summaryRenderer: function(value) {
                        return (value.toFixed(2) );
                    },
                    renderer: function(value) {
                        return (value.toFixed(2));
                    }
                }
              ]
        }
     ]
});
```

when i try to hide the column E .it does it  well but when i try to show it.It shows the subcolumns which was  originaly hidden.

my code for hiding is

```
 myGrid.columns[2].setVisible(flase);
```

for showing i am using

```
myGrid.columns[2].setVisible(true);
```

any help?